# How to extract single value from array in Json string. This value is not a name>value pair

Tags: c#, json

I have the below Json string. I need to use C# to return me "file_1.txt"

```
{
  "value": {
    "filenames": [
      "file_1.txt",
      "file_2.txt"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried Deserialize

```
        var myCustomclassname = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        var string1 = myCustomclassname.value;
        var string2 = myCustomclassname.filenames[0];
```

But it throws

> "'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

I have tried this

```
    JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
    JToken filenamesToken = data.GetValue("filenames");
    List<string> filenames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(filenamesToken.ToString());
```

But it throws

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: How are you reading/parsing this JSON?  Are you deserializing it into a specific class structure?  Into some dynamic structure?  Reading it manually as text?  Something else?

Comment: What have you tried? Which library do you use? `System.Text.Json` or Newtonsoft Json.NET?

Comment: Single value from an array mean what when the array contains multiple? And as simple as it looks still just create a class for that, deserialize the json into the class and then look at the filenames array property of that class and take the element you mean with single from that array.

Comment: To answer all of your questions, I have updated my post to include what I have tried.

Comment: @MikeJohnston: In those examples you appear to be looking for a property called `names` in your data, but the data has no such property.  It has a property called `value`, which itself has a property called `filenames`.  Is this just a typo error?

Comment: @David I corrected the typo now

Comment: @Ralf When I plug this into an online Json to C# Object converter. The output of the C# has 2 objects....      public class Root
    {
        public Value value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public List<string> filenames { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Answered and presumably used the same converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first attempt (deserializing to `dynamic`), you're looking for the `filenames` property in the root of the object:

```
var string2 = myCustomclassname.filenames[0];
```

But it's not in the root of the object.  It's under the `value` property:

```
var string2 = myCustomclassname.value.filenames[0];
```

The same is true in your second attempt:

```
JToken filenamesToken = data.GetValue("filenames");
```

You're missing the `value` property:

```
JToken valueToken = data.GetValue("value");
JToken filenamesToken = valueToken["filenames"];
```

Comment: Perfect if I dont want to create an object beforehand. This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple Class representation for the Json

```
public class Root
{
    public Value value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public List<string> filenames { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the JsonSerializer of your choice to deserialize the Json into the class and access the property you are interested in.

```
 var myLovelyRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myLovelyJson);
 var fileName = myLovelyRoot.value.filenames.First();
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I prefer to not have to create a C# Object beforehand though, so I chose the @Davids answer